# Scroll Top = Scroll Height not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the js that I have in my js file

```
function refreshChat()
    {
        //speed up by selecting the div only once
        var shoutbox = $("#shoutbox");

        //get the height of the scroll (if any)
        var oldScrollH = shoutbox.attr("scrollHeight") - 20;

        //the ajax request
        $.ajax({
        url: 'shoutbox/update.php',
        //disable cache
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            //update the shoutbox
            shoutbox.html(html);
            //get the heigth of the scroll after the update
            var newScrollH = shoutbox.attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newScrollH > oldScrollH)
            {
                //*move* the scroll down using an animation :)
                shoutbox.animate({scrollTop: newScrollH}, 1);
            }
        }   
        });
    }
    //set the refreshChat function to run every *refreshSeconds*
    setInterval(refreshChat, refreshSeconds);


});
```

it works fine in Firefox and IE, but with Google Chrome it constantly flicks. It will scroll to the bottom on page load, but when it calls to the function `refreshChat` it moves back up about halfway up the div.

I also have this in my `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //speed up by selecting the div only once
        var shoutbox = $("#shoutbox");

        //get the height of the scroll (if any)
        var oldScrollH = shoutbox.attr("scrollHeight");

        //the ajax request
        $.ajax({
        url: 'shoutbox/update.php',
        //disable cache
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            //update the shoutbox
            shoutbox.html(html);
            //get the heigth of the scroll after the update
            var newScrollH = shoutbox.attr("scrollHeight");
            if(newScrollH > oldScrollH)
            {
                //*move* the scroll down using an animation :)
                shoutbox.animate({scrollTop: newScrollH}, 1);
            }
        }   
        })
        });
```

so that it will auto load the shoutbox on page load, could this be conflicting with it? It seems logical, but I don't want users to have to wait 3 seconds for the shoutbox to initially load.

Comment: Can you showcase your problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I wouldn't really know how, the shoutbox is php coded so I am not sure how I would go about it as I have never used jsfiddle before.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the chrome developer tools?

Comment: @kira423 what do you mean it's php coded?  It has to make it to the client somehow

Comment: @JohnKoerner no it's not throwing any errors

Comment: @ExplosionPills I dunno I am not really the best with js at all, and wouldn't know how to use the site to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string to int.

**scrollHeight** is custom attribute and i guess its dynamically added so it must string thats why you need to cast it to int.

```
parseInt(shoutbox.attr("scrollHeight"));
```

try this, hope this will solve it.

Comment: that didn't work, but was a flaw in the code so i really appreciate that. For some reason I think that it's not calculating the height right maybe because of the smiley images

Comment: i don't think image has anything to do because you are reading custom attr so only that attr does matter...